# Parsing a Standard Query into JSON Clause Tree

Tags: javascript, java, json, parsing, text-parsing

I want to build a query for my system that could be used by external systems for configuration based on conditions.

On the backend I find it easy to have a JSON Clause tree which would be evaluated recursively.

```
[
  "AND",
  [
    {
      "operator": "eq",
      "field": "section1.fieldabc",
      "value": "value1"
    },
    [
      "OR",
      {
        "operator": "lt",
        "field": "section2.fieldxyz",
        "value": 5000
      },
      {
        "operator": "gt",
        "field": "section2.fieldxyz",
        "value": 1000
      }
    ]
  ]
]
```

or something similar. (Above I have represented it something like an s-expression tree)

The thing is I want it as a JSON Clause Tree in Backend but I don't want the users to need to write anything like this.
It would be great if I can create a query something like JQL (Jira query language) or something.
But I don't want to spend a lot of effort actually making a full proof parser for the language that would convert.

Is there any standardised way to implement this? Maybe a standardised query language which gets converted using a library (in JS or Java).

From the end users perspective I want the above query to be like

```
section1.fieldabc == value1 AND (section2.fieldxyz<5000 OR section2.fieldxyz>10000)
```

Comment: why JS or Java? they're different languages and aren't cross compatible

Comment: @evolutionxbox I have FE on Angular 2 and BE in Java.

So either the conversion from the query to JSON takes place in JS/TS ( Before sent to BE, preprocessed) or it comes to BE and we change it to JSON before sending it to the QueryEvaluatorEngine ( And for storing in DB (as JSONB))

Comment: JSON is a string. If you put the current query into a string it would be valid JSON.

Comment: Okay maybe I wasnt clear.
I want it to be covnerted to a JSON Clause Tree for Processing via The QueryEvaluator. So the i/p for The evaluator would be a JSON Clause Tree.
The input by the user would be in a Query Language.

Now the User sets it in JS Based FE and Query Evaluator is in Java.
I want the query to be converted to a JSON Clause tree anywhere in between before going into the query evaluator or to the DB

See the example above of a JSON Clause Tree and the corresponding query.

Comment: from js you can try [jQuery-query-builder](https://querybuilder.js.org/) or [react-query-builder](https://github.com/vojtechportes/react-query-builder) but the structure is not exactly same

Comment: Given that you are allowing for a pretty large range of complexity for the possible commands you are giving you're end users, it doesn't seem like you will get away with anything but a custom parser of some sort, or at least finding a way to shim sql parsing into something consumable on your java end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrote a (relatively) simple parser in TypeScript that can parse binary operators (with correct order of operations) and constants, handle brackets, global variables and simple field accesses. The source code is available on [my GitHub](https://github.com/SchoofsKelvin/random-snippets/blob/master/src/js-sql-query-parser.ts) *(which may or may not be updated in the future)*, while here's a snippet with a JS version:

```js
const BINARY_OPERATORS = {
    // AND/OR
    'AND': 1,
    'OR': 0,
    // Equal stuff
    '==': 2,
    '!=': 2,
    '<': 2,
    '<=': 2,
    '>': 2,
    '>=': 2,
}

function parseConstant(input) {
    // Numbers (including floats, octals and hexadecimals)
    let match = input.match(/^\s*((?:0[xo]|\d*\.)?\d+)/);
    if (match) {
        const [{ length }, digits] = match;
        if (digits.includes('.')) {
            return [length, { type: 'constant', value: parseFloat(digits) }];
        }
        return [length, { type: 'constant', value: parseInt(digits) }];
    }
    // Strings
    match = input.match(/^(\s*)(["'])/);
    if (match) {
        const [, white, quote] = match;
        let value = '';
        let escape = false;
        for (let i = white.length; i < input.length; i++) {
            const ch = input[i];
            if (ch === '\\' && !escape) {
                escape = true;
            } else if (escape) {
                escape = false;
                value += ch;
            } else if (ch === quote) {
                return [i + 1, { type: 'constant', value }];
            } else {
                value += ch;
            }
        }
        return [white.length];
    }
    // Booleans
    match = input.match(/^\s*(true|false)/);
    if (match) {
        const [{ length }, bool] = match;
        return [length, { type: 'constant', value: bool === 'true' }];
    }
    return [0];
}

function parseVariable(input) {
    const match = input.match(/^\s*(\w+[\w\d]*)/);
    if (!match) return [0];
    return [match[0].length, { type: 'variable', name: match[1] }];
}

function orderBinaryOperations(expr) {
    const { left, right } = expr;
    const priority = BINARY_OPERATORS[expr.operator];
    if (left.type == 'binop' && BINARY_OPERATORS[left.operator] < priority) {
        // LOP < EXP
        // (leftL LOP leftR) EXP exprR) => leftL LOP (leftR EXP exprR)
        return orderBinaryOperations({
            type: 'binop',
            operator: left.operator,
            left: left.left,
            right: {
                type: 'binop',
                operator: expr.operator,
                left: left.right,
                right: expr.right,
            },
        });
    } else if (right.type === 'binop' && BINARY_OPERATORS[right.operator] <= priority) {
        // EXP >= ROP
        // exprL EXP (rightL ROP rightR) => (exprL EXP rightL) ROP rightR
        return orderBinaryOperations({
            type: 'binop',
            operator: right.operator,
            left: {
                type: 'binop',
                operator: expr.operator,
                left: expr.left,
                right: right.left,
            },
            right: right.right,
        });
    }
    return expr;
}

function parsePostExpression(expr, input) {
    if (!expr[1]) return expr;
    const trimmed = input.trimLeft();
    const white = input.length - trimmed.length;
    // Binary operation
    for (const operator in BINARY_OPERATORS) {
        if (trimmed.startsWith(operator)) {
            const offset = expr[0] + white + operator.length;
            const rightResult = parseExpression(trimmed.slice(operator.length));
            if (!rightResult[1]) throw new Error(`Missing right-hand side expression for ${operator}`);
            return parsePostExpression([
                offset + rightResult[0],
                orderBinaryOperations({
                    type: 'binop',
                    operator,
                    left: expr[1],
                    right: rightResult[1],
                })
            ], trimmed.slice(rightResult[0]));
        }
    }
    // Field access
    const match = input.match(/^\.(\w+[\w\d]*)/);
    if (match) {
        const [{ length }, field] = match;
        return parsePostExpression([
            expr[0] + white + length,
            { type: 'field', object: expr[1], field }
        ], trimmed.slice(length));
    }
    return expr;
}

function parseExpression(input) {
    // Constants
    let result = parseConstant(input);
    // Variables
    if (!result[1]) result = parseVariable(input);
    // Brackets
    if (!result[1]) {
        const match = input.match(/^\s*\(/);
        if (match) {
            const [{ length }] = match;
            const brackets = parseExpression(input.slice(length));
            if (brackets[1]) {
                const offset = brackets[0] + length;
                const endBracket = input.slice(offset).match(/^\s*\)/);
                if (!endBracket) throw new Error(`Missing ')' in '${input}'`);
                result = [offset + endBracket[0].length, {
                    type: 'brackets', expr: brackets[1]
                }];
            }
        }
    }
    return parsePostExpression(result, input.slice(result[0]));
}

function parse(input) {
    const [length, expr] = parseExpression(input);
    if (length === input.length) {
        if (expr) return expr;
        throw new Error(`Unfinished expression`);
    }
    if (!expr) throw new Error(`Unexpected character at ${length}`);
    throw new Error(`Unexpected character at ${length}`);
}

const parsed = parse('(section2.fieldxyz<5000 OR section2.fieldxyz>10000) AND section1.fieldabc == value1');
console.log(JSON.stringify(parsed, null, 4));

function formatExpression(expr) {
    if (expr.type === 'binop') {
        // Wrapping in [] so the order of operations is clearly visible
        return `[${formatExpression(expr.left)} ${expr.operator} ${formatExpression(expr.right)}]`;
    } else if (expr.type === 'brackets') {
        return `(${formatExpression(expr.expr)})`;
    } else if (expr.type === 'constant') {
        return JSON.stringify(expr.value);
    } else if (expr.type === 'field') {
        return `${formatExpression(expr.object)}.${expr.field}`;
    } else if (expr.type === 'variable') {
        return expr.name;
    }
    throw new Error(`Unexpected expression type '${expr.type}'`);
}

console.log('=>', formatExpression(parsed));
```

Example output when converted to JSON:

```json
{
    "type": "binop",
    "operator": "AND",
    "left": {
        "type": "brackets",
        "expr": {
            "type": "binop",
            "operator": "OR",
            "left": {
                "type": "binop",
                "operator": "<",
                "left": {
                    "type": "field",
                    "object": {
                        "type": "variable",
                        "name": "section2"
                    },
                    "field": "fieldxyz"
                },
                "right": {
                    "type": "constant",
                    "value": 5000
                }
            },
            "right": {
                "type": "binop",
                "operator": ">",
                "left": {
                    "type": "field",
                    "object": {
                        "type": "variable",
                        "name": "section2"
                    },
                    "field": "fieldxyz"
                },
                "right": {
                    "type": "constant",
                    "value": 10000
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "right": {
        "type": "binop",
        "operator": "==",
        "left": {
            "type": "field",
            "object": {
                "type": "variable",
                "name": "section1"
            },
            "field": "fieldabc"
        },
        "right": {
            "type": "variable",
            "name": "value1"
        }
    }
}
```

I've went with always using objects with a `type` field, although you can still convert the `binop` objects to look like e.g. `['AND', expr1, expr2]`. And instead of simply having binary operations always be on a field that's just a `a.b.c.etc` string, mine is a bit more advanced. Could still add restrictions, though, at least the groundworks are there.

I've tackled this issue because I enjoy writing these kind of things. I actually recommend going with Chandan's suggestion of using [jQuery QueryBuilder](https://querybuilder.js.org/) or [react-query-builder](https://github.com/vojtechportes/react-query-builder), to make it a lot easier and friendlier towards your users.

If you're more targeted towards "power users" which would enjoy an SQL-like syntax, my code could help. There are probably many better libraries out there to help with that, though, which might be more robust in e.g. reporting syntax errors or trying to access non-existant variables/fields. Then again, since my code is only about 150 lines (200 if you include types) and not written too weirdly, it shouldn't be too hard to adapt it for your needs if that suits you better.